# How to set stepTimeout option in CasperJS in test environment?

Tags: casperjs

I faced this problem writing UI test when test just can't finish and there is no default timeout for this. I can set this when creating casper instance like this

```
var casper = casper.create({stepTimeout: 5000});
```

But I can't do this when I launch casper in test mode `casperjs test test.js`. I have an error `Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment`.

Is there any way to set this timeout in test environment?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a preconfigured casper instance in test mode (casperjs **test** ...), so you can't create another with `casper.create()`.

Use this : `casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;` and `casper.options.stepTimeout = 10000;`

Comment: You mean you're stuck in a step, right? You should edit your message for more information. This topic : [Page polls remote url](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/D7KYWJeIprk) might help you.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov You might want to try different locations for this setting like at the beginning of the script *or* inside `test.begin` but before `casper.start` *or* inside `casper.start`.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think increase the stepTimeout will change something, for me your problem is elsewhere. What do you try to achieve? Can we see the html and the js code with the page url?

Answer (score 0):

I used  a global constant TIMEOUT  in my methods to accomplish  this

```
if(ADD_DONATION){
casper.click(DONATION_ADD_TAB);
  casper.waitForSelector(DONOR_WEIGHT_ID, function success(){
        test.pass('Add Donation --> Donations Loaded Successfully') },function timeout(){
          test.fail('Add Donation --> Donations page timeout')},**TIMEOUT**);

  }else
        test.pass('Add Donation -- No Permission to view Add Donations Page');

});
```

Comment: This sets the `waitTimeout`, but not the `stepTimeout` that was asked.